# Spring Async Reference

Tags: asynchronous, spring-3

```
@Bean
public EventHandler eventHandler(){
    EventHandler handler= new EventHandler(session());
    session().registerEventListener(handler);
    return handler;
}

    public class EventHandler implements EventListener{
        @Override
        @Async
        public void notify(Event event) {
                   //do work
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to create an async handler and register it...Doesnt seem to work as I believe Spring will only create the async wrappers after it creates a proxy object around the bean after the bean has been created....how do I work around this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I couldn't call an @Override method with @Async - it would always be called synchronously.
My workaround was to declare another @Service bean with a direct (non-@Override) interface to forward the call to the bean I was calling via an @Override interface.
I figure the proxying just doesn't work via base class calls.